# Origin of the following equation

Tags: reference-request, reflection, translation-request, searching

```
float xx = acceleration.x;
float yy = acceleration.y;
float zz = acceleration.z;

float dot = (px * xx) + (py * yy) + (pz * zz);
float a = ABS(sqrt(px * px + py * py + pz * pz));
float b = ABS(sqrt(xx * xx + yy * yy + zz * zz));

dot /= (a * b);
```

I run into the equation above on [github](https://github.com/pdetagyos/Pedometer/blob/master/Pedometer/ViewController.m), but I don't know what is it name, origin, field(DSP, some kind of high pass filter)?

$$ result= \frac{x_{prev} * x + y_{prev} * y + z_{prev} * z }{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} * \sqrt{(x_{prev}^2 + y_{prev}^2 + z_{prev}^2)}} $$

If my question is too obvious please forgive my ignorance, I hope that it is a real question and it not will be closed.

Comment: I don't know if it has an "official" name, but it looks like an application of the geometric definition of the dot product between $(x,y,z)$ and $(x_{prev},y_{prev},z_{prev})$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition. In this case, $result$ equals the cosine of the angle between the two vectors.